# How to pass a list from one action to another in Struts 2 without using session?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am displaying a list in my JSP as shown below:

```
<%@page  contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"language="java"pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s"uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>xxx</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<s:form name="tableForm"method="post">
<th>
<s:submit action="verify" key="Add"></s:submit>
</th>
<s:hidden name="propagateList" value="%{formList}"/>
<table border="1">

<tr>
<th >ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>System</th>
</tr>


<s:iterator value="formList">
<tr>
<td><s:checkbox name="checked" fieldValue="%{#attr.ID}" theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
</td>
<td><s:property value="NAME"/></td>
<td><s:property value="STATUS"/></td>
<td><s:property value="TYPE"/></td>
<td><s:property value="UNIT"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>

</table>

</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I want to pass the list **formList** to another action when I click on **Add** button without having to hit the database to fetch the list **formList** once again.

I tried using  `<s:hidden name="propagateList" value="%{formList}"/>` but it does not work.

This list contains more than 1000 records , so is there any way to pass this list from the jsp to another action in Struts 2 without using session?

Comment: Why not use a session? It's common to use it between actions.

Comment: Because the list is too large, and I thought its not a good practice to store so much data in the session. So, I'm looking for some other alternative

Comment: @user2077648 you are talking about two separate requests here. When the first request comes the JSP is shown with the 1000 records to the user. When user clicks on the add button.. a second request is sent to the server. So sharing the formList between these two can't simply be done via a hidden field.. session would be the easiest

Comment: More over you don't required the list in the session nor submit it to the action. All you need is just to update a new record. Then after updates repopulate the list again to reflect updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question "how to pass a List from ActionA to ActionB without using the Session":

- in case of a `List<String>` :

  ```
  <s:iterator value="formList" status="row">
      <s:hidden name="formList[%{#row.index}]" />
  </s:iterator>
  ```

This will iterate through your whole List, and will generate an `<s:hidden/>` element for every element of the List; this way, you can pass an un-altered List from one Action to another.

- in case of a `List<Object>` , where the object is that you've posted in the page:

  ```
  <s:iterator value="formList" status="row">
      <s:hidden name="formList[%{#row.index}].id" />
      <s:hidden name="formList[%{#row.index}].name" />
      <s:hidden name="formList[%{#row.index}].status" />
      <s:hidden name="formList[%{#row.index}].type" />
      <s:hidden name="formList[%{#row.index}].unit" />
  </s:iterator>
  ```

Exactly as before, this will iterate through your whole List, generating five  elements for every object of the List.

Using this concept, you can alter the List by using interactive tags (textfield, select, etc) instead of read-only tags (hidden, property etc):

```
<s:iterator value="formList" status="row">
    <s:hidden name="formList[%{#row.index}].id" />
    <s:textfield name="formList[%{#row.index}].name" value="name" />        
    <s:hidden   name="formList[%{#row.index}].status" />
    <s:property value="status" />
    <s:textfield name="formList[%{#row.index}].type" value="type" />
    <s:textfield name="formList[%{#row.index}].unit" value="unit" />
</s:iterator>
```

Of course your List will be vulnerable to client-side changes, every user able to press F12 will be able to modify your List, then you should be careful.

You could, for example, put only the **ID**s in the **session**, inject the List in the JSP, then when receiving the data back, match the **ID**s of List coming from the page with the **ID**s you have in Session, for checking the integrity of the data posted (no new IDs, no double IDs etc)

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code isn't working is because

```
<s:hidden name="propagateList" value="%{formList}"/>
```

Doesn't do what you think it does.

This sets a hidden field on the HTML page called `propagateList` to the value of `formList.toString()`. This is obviously not useful.

You need to set is as CSV or JSON or some serialized from and then deserialize it when is sent back by the client.

There seems to be client/sever side confusion.

First you get the `formlist` from the db and use it to render your page. This is an HTML page, it is sent to the client.

The client renders the HTML with your `formList` and the does something, clicks `add` for example.

The result of the add is that the client sends a POST request back to the server with the data.

Do you really think it is more efficient to send 1000 values back to the server in serialized from and then deserialize them back into a `List` rather than hit the db? For one thing it means that a POST request which should be very small becomes rather large.

Use a `Session` or maybe cache it locally in some sort of `static` cache.