# How to pass an object inside a jsp page [s:iterator] to an action class?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, iterator, struts-action

I have a JSP page displaying an object called `docsFacebook`. I need to pass this object to an action class in order to process its content. How to do it?

JSP

```xml
<s:iterator value="docsFacebook">
    <p>
       <img src="images/fb.png" />
       <b><s:property value="Newspaper"/></b>       
       <s:property value="Date"/></p>               
       <p><s:property value="Message"/></p>              
       <p><a href=<s:property value="Link_url"/>>
       <s:property value="Link_url"/></a>
    </p>
    <br></br>           
</s:iterator>
```

In the same page I have a button with a link to an action class..

```xml
<a href="<s:url action="display" />">Facebook</a>
```

How to retrieve this data from that action class?

struts.xml

```xml
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="doFirstQuery" class="action.FirstQuery">
            <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">error.jsp</result>               
        </action>
        <action name="doFollowingQuery" class="action.FollowingQuery">
            <result name="success">success.jsp</result>                         
        </action> 
        <action name="display" class="action.Display">
            <result name="success">dis.jsp</result>                         
        </action>           
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: So you want to pass `docsFacebook` object to `display` action?

Comment: Do you want to pass or retrieve the data or both? What did you try?

Comment: Yes, i want to pass docsFacebook to display action in order to visualize that object inside a new jsp page linked to that class

Comment: what is the obj type `docsFacebook`.

Comment: docsFacebook is of type array Risultato[]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class Risultato {
 String Date;
 String Id;
 String Index;
 String Message;
 String N_likes;
 String Newspaper;
 String Link_url; 
 
 public Risultato(String date, String id, String index, String message,    String n_likes, String newspaper,
   String link_url) {
  super();
  Date = date;
  Id = id;
  Index = index;
  Message = message;
  N_likes = n_likes;
  Newspaper = newspaper;
  Link_url = link_url;
 }

getters and setters....

Answer (score 1):

#### 1 - Appropriate accessors / mutators:

Since you are reading an array, you need an **array getter** in the source action:

```java
public Risultato[] getDocsFacebook(){...}
```

then in the page you are choosing a single element, and hence you need an **object setter** in the destination action:

```java
public void setDocsFacebook(Risultato risultato){...}
```

---

#### 2 - Sending the object:

To send the object you have two problems:

- the properties printed with  are not form elements, but plain text; you need then to use an hidden field for everyone of them to send the value:

  ```xml
  <s:property value="foo" />
  <s:hidden    name="foo" />

  <s:textfield name="bar" />
  ```
- To send a single object from within an iterated collection, you need to specify an index with OGNL. **The whole thing is described quite well [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16517995/1654265)**, be sure to read it all.

#### 3 - The INPUT result

Your (awfully italian-localized) logs are telling you that, since there is some kind of conversion or validation error, an INPUT result is returned.

INPUT is different from ERROR because it indicates a recoverable error in the data inserted by the user, and it should ask the user to enter them again, instead for example of land to an error page.

I strongly suggest you to read [what the INPUT result is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23448616/1654265).

Comment: thank you. So:
in the action class Display(destination action called by my jsp page) i have to define a variable of type Risultato because I have to read each element of the list...i need also getter and setter methods.
In my jsp page how can i use the hidden tag to get the values of the different fields of type Risultato?

Comment: I've decided to solve my problem using the interface SessionAware. I have put my object in the session but i'm not able to retrieve it from my jsp page.

Comment: You need to stop coding and read a bit about how it works. It would be a lot easier. IF you can choose *only one* element in the JSP to send to *display* action, then you need a setter for a Risultato. If you can choose *multiple* elements at once, you need a setter for Risultato[], or List<Risultato>. The hidden tag usage it's in the answer I've linked in the point 2. As said, **be sure to read it all**...

Answer (score 0):

Create a `variablename` (some property to hold the `docsFacebook` value) property in `Display` action class and write setter and getter methods to it.

If `docsFacebook` is of type `Risultato` then

In `Dsiaply` action class

```
private Risultato variablename;

public Risultato setVariablename(Risultato variablename)
{
     ............
}
public Risultato getVariablename()
{
     .............
}
```

Now in `JSP` call action class method

```
 <a href='display?variablename=<s:property value="docsFacebook"/>'>Facebook</a>
```

If you clicks on link `Facebook` the `display` action class method will be called.

If `docsFacebook` is of type `Risultato[]` then replace `Risultato` with `Risultato[]` in `Display` action class.

Comment: I've replied to you in my new answer...@Satya

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action action.Display and result input

Comment: Did you write any validations for this `Display`. since it wants result type input.

Comment: it seems the parameter has not been passed correctly.