# How to get value of generated row value for another action when generated submit button is clicked

Tags: html, forms, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I want to know how to get dynamically generated table row value (eg. empp_id)  when clicking submit button that is generated for each row dynamically.

Below is my code. I used  to generate each row and submit button for each row. I don't know how to use submit button to get and pass the value of 'id' column to another action.

Struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN" 
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">


        <action name="edit" class="com.ojt.database.EditUserAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">edituser.jsp</result>
            <result name="error"></result>
        </action>

</struts>
```

EditUserAction.java

```
package com.ojt.database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class EditUserAction extends ActionSupport {
    List<User> liUser=null;


    public List<User> getLiUser() {
        return liUser;
    }


    public void setLiUser(List<User> liUser) {
        this.liUser = liUser;
    }


    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        Connection conn;
        String ret = "error";
        try {

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            liUser=new ArrayList<User>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                user.setName(rs.getString(2));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString(3));
                liUser.add(user);   
            }
            conn.close();
            ret = "success";
            System.out.println(ret);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ret = "error";
            System.out.println(ret);
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

edituser.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net/el"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="20" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Password</th>

        </tr>

        <s:iterator value="liUser">
            <tr>
                <td><s:property value="id" /></td>

                <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="password" /></td>
                <td><s:submit value="Edit" theme="simple" action="review" method="POST"/></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I need your help please.
I can't go any further, i am stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you use `<s:property/>`, you are not creating a form tag, but just simple text. 
   To send something printed with `<s:property/>`, [use an `<s:hidden/>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16517995/1654265) in conjunction with it.
2. To send a list of object from JSP, you need to use the [IteratorStatus object to specify an index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343980/1654265).
3. You are not even using a form. You need a form to POST something in the standard, non-AJAX way.
4. You need two action's methods, or two actions: one to display the data, the other to edit it. 
   In your `execute()` method you are initializing your list every time: 
   `liUser=new ArrayList<User>();`, 
   so the one coming from the page will always be lost.

You are in deep water. I suggest you to stop for a moment and take a closer look at HTML, HTTP, Struts2 and its tags, otherwise you will get frustrated quite soon.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @Andrea.

Comment: I fix with this code as you mentioned..
<s:hidden id="rowId" value="%{id}"/>
<s:property value="id"/>
and my project work fine.
thanks again @AndreaLigios